# How to start a remote thread in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, producer-consumer

I have an apllication where there are three folders. I am trying to implement the producer consumer concept using LinkedBlockingQueue.

Folder 1:
Contains a class which has a shared queue

```
public static BlockingQueue sharedQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue();
```

From a method in this class I try to call the Producer thread and the Consumer thread both of which reside in separate files.

```
  Thread updateThread = new Thread(new Producer(sharedQueue));
  Thread takeThread = new Thread(new Consumer(sharedQueue));
  updateThread.start();
  takeThread.start();
```

Folder 2:Contains the producer thread class as follows:

```
public class Producer implements Runnable {        
    private final BlockingQueue Queue;

    public Producer(BlockingQueue sharedQueue){    
        Queue = sharedQueue;
    }

    public void run()
    {
         while (Thread.currentThread() != null) {
         Random random = new Random();
         int pos = random.nextInt(productList.size());              
         String query = "insert into tab1 values("+pos+")";
         Queue.put(query);  
    }
}
```

Folder 3: Contains the consumer class as follows:

```
public class Consumer implements Runnable{

    private final BlockingQueue queue;
    Collection<String> joblist;   
    public Consumer (BlockingQueue sharedQueue) {
    queue = sharedQueue;
    MonitoringForm.txtInforamtion.append("hi"+sharedQueue.size());
    joblist = new ArrayList<String>();
}

@Override
public void run() {

    while(true){
        try {             
            for(int i = 0; i < queue.size(); i++)
            {
                joblist.add(queue.take().toString());
                MonitoringForm.txtInforamtion.append("What we got "+queue.take().toString());
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Consumer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(60*1000); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
     }

    }
}
}
```

Can somebody tell me how to make sure that the data added to the shared queue by Producer class can be taken by Consumer class. The consumer consumes the data every minute. Not necessary that data is consumed as soon as it is produced. Calling the Consumer and Producer threads is not working as I have them in separate directories. Do I have to use remote method invocation? Is it possible for threads?

Comment: Do you experience any problem with your code? What do you expect to happen, what actually happened?

Comment: I am not able to invoke the Producer and Consumer threads since they reside in separate folders. I get a "cannot find symbol" error for Producer and Consumer.

Comment: @user3339716, so you have not imported these classes in your third Class

Comment: "Cannot find symbol" most probably means you have not imported the classes Consumer and Producer that you are using. It is a compiler error, it has nothing to do with running threads.

Comment: Ok.Thank you. Do I have to import it as a package. I am new to java and have less of the available methods. The Producer and Consumer classes lie in a directory "phase2/Scheduler/Producer.java" and the class that calls it lies in the directory "phase2/Middleware/ProducerConsumer.java".

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample code I wrote which can help you understand the concept:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

/**
 * We want a Producer thread to create random values, and the Consumer thread to
 * consume it. One caveat is that if the Producer has already created a random
 * value, which the Consumer thread hasn't consumed yet, the Producer thread
 * blocks or waits. On the flip side, the Consumer thread waits for the Producer
 * thread to produce some value if the Producer thread hasn't already.
 * 
 * Write a program to simulate such a situation.
 */

public class ProducerConsumerCommunication
{

  private volatile boolean running = true;
  private ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer> buffer = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1);
  private Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

  private class ProducerTask implements Runnable
  {
    public void run()
    {
      while (running)
      {
        try
        {
          Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(2000));
          Integer value = random.nextInt();
          buffer.put(value); // Blocks if buffer is full.
          System.out.println("Value Put: " + value);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
  }

  private class ConsumerTask implements Runnable
  {
    public void run()
    {
      while (running)
      {
        try
        {
          Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(2000));
          Integer value = buffer.take(); // Blocks if buffer is empty.
          System.out.println("Value Taken: " + value);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
  }

  public ProducerConsumerCommunication()
  {
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    service.execute(new ProducerTask());
    service.execute(new ConsumerTask());
    service.shutdown();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    new ProducerConsumerCommunication();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the traditional Consumer/Producer concept the Consumer waits on a resource. And whenever the Producer pushes anything on the Queue it notifies the Consumer via notify() / notifyAll()

Producer :

```
queue.put(query) ;
obj.notifyAll();
```

---

Consumer :

```
while(true)
{
 try {
        obj.wait();
 }catch (InterruptedException e) { 
     } 
// get data from Queue
data = queue.take();

}
```

Refer to the following link for more information : [example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaexamples/thread_procon.htm)

Answer (score 0):

To run the Producer and Consumer in the fashion like when the Producer produces something in the queue he should Notify the Consumer, and when the Consumer consumed from the queue he should notify to the Producer to produce something in the queue,

To implement your problem in that way you have to use

wait and Notify method if you have one producer and one consumer.
and if you have multiple consumer then you have to use NotifyAll method as well of Object Class,

And in your Consumer if you get this line printed to your console "**What we got**" then you are sure that Consumer has consumed something from the queue

Comment: @@user3339716, so have you imported these Producer,Consumer classes in your third Class